# How to check for duplicate entries in MySQL when importing from Coldfusion into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, import, duplicates

I have a CSV import into MySQL and after getting my first duplicate-entry-error I'm looking for some functionality to check for duplicates BEFORE importing to MySQL.

I'm running `Coldfusion8, MySQL5.0.88`.

My import first goes into an intermediate table (import_pricat_csv) before actually commiting to the main database. When filling the intermediate table I'm doing all my import validation like so:

```
 <cfquery datasource="db">
    UPDATE import_pricat_csv
    SET error= "true", errorMsg= "invalid EAN"
    WHERE iln = <cfqueryparam value = "#Session.loginID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="13"> 
    AND error= "no" 
    AND (ean is null OR NOT (ean REGEXP '[0-9]{13}' OR ean REGEXP '[0-9]{12}'))
 </cfquery>
```

This checks the import_pricat for errors before it's being commited to the database. I know I can `INSERT IGNORE` into MySQL but I need to do it like this to create an import-error report.

I need to add a rule to check whether the `ean` to be imported is already in the actual database table `products`.

I'm trying this, but it does not work:

```
<cfquery datasource="db">
    UPDATE import_pricat_csv
    SET error= "yes", errorMsg= "duplicate EAN"
    WHERE iln = <cfqueryparam value = "#Session.loginID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="13"> 
        AND error= "no" 
        AND ean IN (SELECT p.ean FROM products AS p WHERE p.ean = ean )
</cfquery>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally would use `LOAD DATA FROM FILE` to import the CSV data into a temporary (and identical) table. Then with all the new data in this temporary table you can then query against this it and compare to the "master" in order to determine if the value exists.

```
<cfquery name="qLoadTempData" datasource="xyz">
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'abc.csv'
  INTO TABLE 'temp_table_name'
  [rest of the query]
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="qCheckExisting" datasource="xyz">
  SELECT x, y, z
  FROM temp_table AS a 
  WHERE
    a.ean NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM main_table AS b WHERE b.ean = a.ean)
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="qCheckExisting">
  <!--- All the ean's that are not in the main table --->
  <!--- now insert into the main table --->
</cfloop>

<!--- Empty out the temp table ready for next import --->
```

The only small thing to remember with this that if the CSV file is not formatted correctly none of the data will be imported to the temp table. It will however be a **much** quicker method of importing a CSV file.

Comment: Re: *none of the data will be imported to the temp table* - You could also use `varchar` columns. Then validate after the import with a few queries. Also, as long as you are using a temporary table, you can skip the `cfloop` and use a `JOIN` to do any inserts/updates.